# setting basic authentication c# to call a soap web service

Tags: c#, authentication, servicemanager

As suggested by Julian i accept this is not much different but still face difficulty may be because of the nature of the web service the client has exposed. anyway this is my latest code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sherpa_service.SherpaInstanceType create_instance = new sherpa_service.SherpaInstanceType();
            sherpa_service.StringType category = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType assignment_group = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType assignee = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType area = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType sub_area = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType impact = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType urgency = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType contact_number = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType title = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType email_id = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            sherpa_service.StringType[] desc = new sherpa_service.StringType[3];
            desc[0] = new sherpa_service.StringType();
            desc[0].Value = "sample description from .net";
            sherpa_service.SherpaInstanceTypeDescription description = new sherpa_service.SherpaInstanceTypeDescription();
            description.Description = desc;




            category.Value = "Finance / Treasury / Tax Apps";
            assignment_group.Value = "Procure to Pay";
            area.Value = "Finance Apps";
            sub_area.Value = "concur";
            assignee.Value = "apadiyar";
            email_id.Value = "seethak@non.agilent.com";
            contact_number.Value = "9884525412";

            create_instance.ContactNumber = contact_number;
            create_instance.EXternalEmail = email_id;
            create_instance.Category = category;
            create_instance.AssignmentGroup = assignment_group;
            create_instance.Assignee = assignee;
            create_instance.Area = area;
            create_instance.Subarea = sub_area;
            create_instance.Description = description;

            sherpa_service.SherpaKeysType create_key = new sherpa_service.SherpaKeysType();
            sherpa_service.SherpaModelType create_model = new sherpa_service.SherpaModelType();
            sherpa_service.CreateSherpaRequest1 create_incident = new sherpa_service.CreateSherpaRequest1();

            create_model.keys = create_key;
            create_model.instance = create_instance;
            create_incident.CreateSherpaRequest = new sherpa_service.CreateSherpaRequest();
            create_incident.CreateSherpaRequest.model = create_model;
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);

            //binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
                                          HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/SM/7/ws");

            ChannelFactory<sherpa_service.Sherpa> factory =
             new ChannelFactory<sherpa_service.Sherpa>(binding, address);
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "xxx";
            sherpa_service.Sherpa proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            sherpa_service.CreateSherpaResponse1 respo = proxy.CreateSherpa(create_incident);
            Console.WriteLine(respo);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Below is the exception almost back to square 1! am still referring the link you had given , but hardly i could figure out the mistake .

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP
>   request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>   The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic
>   realm="CASM"'.'
>
> WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

[please see this image to seethe multiple classes created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP2se.jpg)

***also i want to ask then what is the purpose of the "sherpa client" class created by the .net IDE itself when i first added the web reference.?***

Comment: Don't manually inject the header into the HTTP request, let WCF do that for you by configuring the binding's security. See duplicate.

Comment: i have changed the coded added new one and explained how min is different.  is it possible for you to help ?